# Get image height and width from a dataurl

Tags: javascript, php, image

Having the source of an image as a dataurl, is there a way to get the image height and width either in javascript or PHP so that I can set these as properties of a div?

or is there a better way to make the div scale to the image size. Consider that the image is used as `background-image` property in the CSS of the div.

Comment: you can, but it will take some time to fetch a 2nd copy of the image, read the height once it loads, and then modify your div's style. it could be quite flashy onscreen, hard-coding is better UX.

Comment: OK. Its actually true. As in question isn't there any way to make the div scale based on background image once loaded?

Comment: i don't believe so. going the other way is easy (bg to fit div). you might try a  non-interactive oversize div that doesn't scale the image and is transparent where the image doesn't reach. pointer-events:none;

Comment: In JavaScript you can scale the display div to what you need it as.You'll just need to pass the height and width of the image from PHP to JavaScript. But I believe you should leave the image rendering to PHP, unless you got some flashy JavaScript. .

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Cannot seem to find a way to get image properties from PHP. Or maybe also from PostgreSQL as the data is stored in a text field in PG

Comment: Perhaps use [PHP getimagesizefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) Get the size of an image from a base-64 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the aspect ratio of the image then you can create a responsive `<div>` which 'mimics' the native `<img>` element as the page resizes.

For example if you have an image that is 300x180 - then the aspect ratio is

> 1 : 0.6

(180/300=0.6) This means if the image is 100% wide, then it is 60% high.

```
.image {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-300-180-1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wca83gjn/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same problem.
I have code that works but am not sure it is optimal.
This assumes you are running in a browser context.

```
function onPhotoDrop(dropEvent) {
  dropEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let browser grab it
  
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(eInner) {
    const dataURL = eInner.target.result;
    // Create a new img element and set its src attribute to the dropped image
    // We need to do this to obtain the photos size.
    const newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.src = dataURL;
    newImg.onload = function() {
      // we need to wait till the image is loaded before proceeding.
      console.assert(newImg.width);
      console.assert(newImg.height);
      
      // here you would make a call to a function with the DataURL, width and height.
    }
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(dropEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```

Then you might pass it on for resizing to a reasonable size for storage

```
function resizeImageSrc(
  elImg, // img.src must be set.
  minWidth,
  maxWidth,
  minHeight, 
  maxHeight) {
    console.assert(minWidth <= maxWidth);
    console.assert(minHeight <= maxHeight);
    console.assert(elImg.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img');
    console.assert(elImg.src);
    console.assert(elImg.width);
    console.assert(elImg.height);

  let wScale = 1;
  if (elImg.width > maxWidth) {
    wScale = maxWidth / elImg.width;
  } else if (elImg.width < minWidth){
    wScale = minWidth / elImg.width;
  }

  let hScale = 1;
  if (elImg.height > maxHeight) {
    hScale = maxHeight / elImg.height;
  } else if (elImg.height < minHeight){
    hScale = minHeight / elImg.height;
  }

  // shrink or grow to fit - favor the smaller scale
  let scale = hScale < wScale ? hScale : wScale;

  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = Math.floor(elImg.width * scale);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(elImg.height * scale);
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(elImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  elImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  // or just return canvas.toDataURL(); if that's what you want.
}
```